# zend mail not working in social engine

Tags: php, zend-framework, socialengine

I am trying to set up my own send mail function inside social engine controller. It is failing with no errors. Please help!

Here is the code I am using to send mail. I have put it inside classifieds index controller.

```
use Zend\Mail\Message;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\Smtp as SmtpTransport;
use Zend\Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions;

    $message = new Message();
$message->addTo('to@email.com')
        ->addFrom('from@email.com')
        ->setSubject('Greetings and Salutations!')
        ->setBody("Sorry, I'm going to be late today!");

      // Setup SMTP transport using LOGIN authentication
      $transport = new SmtpTransport();
      $options   = new SmtpOptions(array(
        'name'              => 'localhost.localdomain',
        'host'              => 'smtp.mandrillapp.com',
          'port' => '587',
        'connection_class'  => 'login',
        'connection_config' => array(
        'username' => 'my@email.com',
        'password' => '*********',
    ),
));
$transport->setOptions($options);
$transport->send($message);
```

Thanks!

Comment: How do you know it's failing?

Comment: Its not sending the mail.

Comment: Try looking at the error logs and wrap the `setOptions()` an `send()` into a try-catch block for easier debugging. Did you tried with a different SMTP provider like google?

Comment: Nope. I have the same SMTP working in other apps. Will put it in try catch and get back to you in a bit.

Comment: ok. I put it inside try catch and its still not doing anything. I am sending the request via xmlhttprequest and its returning some html page as response. I am totally lost here.

Comment: @Stanimir I tried logging it manually. Still there was no log.

Comment: Show us the rest of the code, including the javascript.

Comment: did you check the mail server?

Comment: Its not even hitting the action method. Its returning some html page (im assuming some sort of error page). I did try to make sense of it, but it looked like some template.

Comment: @Stanimir : The issue is with adding an action method to a zend controller in social engine. The mail thingy should work if it hits the action method I believe.

Comment: True.. It wasn't hitting the method at all.. I had to ditch the idea in the end.